# Devise locale customisation for passwords renewal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-recoverable

I am trying to customise my errors messages in Devise for the password renewal when the user has forgotten their password. I did all translations and customisations right for `registrations` but for `passwords` I am a bit struggling.

In my **passwords/new** view I have the usual helper call :

```
<%= devise_error_messages! %>
```

But the translation that is fetched from the locale file is this one :

```
translation missing: fr.errors.messages.not_saved
```

This is a bit strange as this message is the same used for `registrations` and is set with "Your account has not been saved" at the moment in my app. But in this case this is not about saving an account but rather confirming a renewal email has been sent.

(of course, on top of this, I have an error message related to the email field  which shows correctly)

Is it tweakable ?

**EDIT EDIT**

Ok it seems it is coming from this bit of code from Devise error helper :

```
sentence = I18n.t("errors.messages.not_saved",
                      :count => resource.errors.count,
                      :resource => resource.class.model_name.human.downcase)
```

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/helpers/devise_helper.rb

Any idea I could tweak this bit of code so that it is different for each of Devise subcontrollers inside the Devise namespace ?